# laravel login refresh page

Tags: php, laravel, authorization

My laravel project doesn`t working on the hosting.But everything works perfectly on the local server(

When i switch to mysite.com, the index page "login" and enter the data in login form, tpage just refreshed

At the same time, if I go to mysite.com/register, I will be able to register a new user and write this data to the Users table in my database

I try make routes for test

```
Route::get('/test', function(){
  return User::All();

//this returned all users in DB(ill check connection with my DB)

});
Route::get('/test', function(){
  $user = Auth::user();
 print_r($user);

//this returned NULL

});
```

I understand the Auth::login function writes the authenticated user to a session and fills the memoer_token field into the database in the user table. In the table itself token is written, but in the session nothing is written.

But idk how to fix it, if it`s true

**UPD:**
I tried to step by step replace my project files with an earlier version (which works correctly).

I find were is my problem. In "resource" folder - file login.blade
In last version i changed standard input "email" to "username"
And now I write the field username
Judging from the above, the problem is that he is expecting a return email? Perhaps somewhere in the validation of data? And why then in the local version of the site everything works well?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    protected $redirectTo = '/user';

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    // protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    protected function redirectTo() 
    {
        if (Auth::user()->role === User::IS_ADMIN && Auth::user()->user_verify === 1) {
            return '/admin';
        }elseif(Auth::user()->role === User::IS_USER && Auth::user()->user_verify === 1 || Auth::user()->role === User::IS_USER && Auth::user()->user_verify === 0){
            return '/user';
        }

        
    }
}
```

```
Route::get('/', function () {
  if(Auth::check()){

    $user = Auth::user();

    if($user->role == 1 && $user->user_verify == 1){
      return redirect('/admin');
    }
    elseif($user->role == 0  && $user->user_verify == 1 
    || $user->role == 0  && $user->user_verify == NULL
    || $user->role == 0  && $user->user_verify == 2){

      return redirect('/user');

    }
  }else{
    return view('auth.login');
  }
});
```

Comment: What does your `laravel.log` say?

Comment: app/storage/logs/laravel.log is empty

Comment: Are you sure that the request is sent to the correct route? Did you clear your view and route cache and dump the composer autoload?

Comment: @Aless55 I updated the question, found a new nuance. Look please, maybe this information will be useful and help to understand

Comment: post the code of your ``/login`` route / controller method !!

Comment: ``Auth::user()`` will obviously return `NULL` if no user has ben authenticated which is the case here!

Comment: @OMiShah I understand that, I’m just trying to give as much information as I can to make it possible

Comment: make sure to to run php artisan view:clear and php artisan cache:clear when you deploy to server. Your view could be cached and you're seeing an old version

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem!

In the LoginController.php file, override the username method by which field to log in. A small email and name input example

```
public function username(): string
{
   $login = request()->input('email');
   $field = filter_var($login, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'name';
   request()->merge([$field => $login]);
   return $field;
}
```